# PyQGIS save raster as rendered image, then use GDAL tools on it

Tags: qgis, gdal, pyqgis, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I have tried to use the code from [QGis Save Raster as Rendered Image](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68803/qgis-save-raster-as-rendered-image?noredirect=1#comment207705_68803). `i` is a raster layer:

```py
pipelayer = i
pipeextent = pipelayer.extent()
pipewidth, pipeheight = (pipelayer.width(),
                         pipelayer.height())
piperenderer = pipelayer.renderer()
pipeprovider = pipelayer.dataProvider()
crs = pipelayer.crs().toWkt()
pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
pipe.set(pipeprovider.clone())
pipe.set(piperenderer.clone())
pipedFile = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(),
                         safeLayerName + '_pipe.tif')
print pipedFile
file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(pipedFile)
file_writer.writeRaster(pipe,
                        pipewidth,
                        pipeheight,
                        pipeextent,
                        pipelayer.crs())

in_raster = pipedFile
prov_raster = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(),
                           'json_' + safeLayerName +
                           '_prov.tif')
out_raster = dataPath + '.png'
crsSrc = i.crs()
crsDest = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326)
xform = QgsCoordinateTransform(crsSrc, crsDest)
extentRep = xform.transform(i.extent())
extentRepNew = ','.join([unicode(extentRep.xMinimum()),
                         unicode(extentRep.xMaximum()),
                         unicode(extentRep.yMinimum()),
                         unicode(extentRep.yMaximum())])
processing.runalg("gdalogr:warpreproject", in_raster,
                  i.crs().authid(), "EPSG:4326", "", 0, 1,
                  5, 2, 75, 6, 1, False, 0, False, "",
                  prov_raster)
processing.runalg("gdalogr:translate", prov_raster, 100,
                  True, "", 0, "", extentRepNew, False, 0,
                  0, 75, 6, 1, False, 0, False, "",
                  out_raster)
```

It doesn't work, instead giving me the unstyled raster as final output. I really don't understand the problem, because the output of `writeRaster` (the file `pipedFile`) *is* styled, so the process from the answer linked to above is working. It's just that when I try to use the output image to run through GDAL's `warpreproject` and `translate`, it somehow reverts to the unstyled raster.

What have I done wrong?

**UPDATE**: The output of `QgsRasterFileWriter` *is* styled. The output of `warpreproject` is *not* styled, but the `.tif` is accompanied by a `.aux.xml` file which appears to have colour information in it:

```xml
<PAMDataset>
  <PAMRasterBand band="1">
    <Histograms>
      <HistItem>
        <HistMin>-0.498046875</HistMin>
        <HistMax>255.498046875</HistMax>
        <BucketCount>256</BucketCount>
        <IncludeOutOfRange>0</IncludeOutOfRange>
        <Approximate>1</Approximate>
        <HistCounts>314|4|3|2|3|5|4|4|5|8|10|9|16|16|23|26|37|46|58|62|69|77|77|94|127|94|131|136|133|162|169|172|171|184|200|186|207|196|186|177|179|194|182|182|178|177|181|195|196|196|195|195|179|226|206|215|193|197|202|212|207|206|232|204|229|253|233|240|248|234|234|268|240|238|259|286|268|287|259|264|255|267|268|271|256|321|277|284|317|286|290|277|312|334|319|325|323|310|349|357|347|326|337|338|336|383|374|349|411|382|382|417|406|405|414|427|404|434|447|430|468|424|446|442|450|461|448|458|457|459|412|414|469|466|443|475|464|472|481|519|504|458|473|481|514|523|522|494|542|580|604|623|686|648|707|763|808|799|819|853|932|1046|1062|1118|1145|1215|1293|1393|1335|1392|1390|1317|1232|1247|1215|1088|1032|896|847|731|708|666|608|634|556|500|484|456|433|408|406|401|386|388|414|414|387|382|340|346|382|385|368|348|334|376|359|318|339|326|357|315|319|357|333|328|329|310|344|295|300|351|347|324|358|349|363|361|347|396|386|433|395|434|479|473|523|550|644|655|672|778|882|1014|1183|1400|1681|2075|2531|3529|4851|7235|10793|60773|7297|1999</HistCounts>
      </HistItem>
    </Histograms>
    <Metadata>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_MAXIMUM">255</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_MEAN">203.31482680479</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_MINIMUM">0</MDI>
      <MDI key="STATISTICS_STDDEV">63.158702013579</MDI>
    </Metadata>
  </PAMRasterBand>
</PAMDataset>
```

The output of `translate` is *not* styled, and has no additional file. However, since it's a PNG not a GeoTIFF, that's perhaps the explanation.

I've tried looking at the `expand` option of `translate`, but that gives me image files which do not display in a web browser - I've not investigated why.

**UPDATE 2**: No, using `expand` results in *no* output file at all. Wondering about trying `pct2rgb`.

**UPDATE 3**: I'm wondering if file locking is causing the problems. Could it be?

Comment: The Processing calls are inherited code. Does warpreproject have completely the wrong arguments? If so, I don't know how it works at all.

Comment: Just a guess but for `gdalogr:translate`, try replacing `prov_raster` with `prov_raster['OUTPUT']`.

Comment: No, `prov_raster` is just a string with the path to that file, so I get `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Answer (score 2):

You should understand that when you save the file from the QgsRenderer as in your code:

```
piperenderer = pipelayer.renderer()
pipe.set(piperenderer.clone())
file_writer.writeRaster(pipe...
```

You are not saving the raster styled, instead you are saving the actual RGB file that represents that visualization, so it is not classified or styled, but it is like you've taken a print screen of the rendered image.

So gdalwarp and translate can't change this, as it is hardcoded in the image's bands, what must be happening is that they are clipping by a single band or so, I have to check it thorughly.

## EDIT

I can see in the xml file you provided that the raster has now only one band

```
<PAMRasterBand band="1">
```

There should be the tags:

```
<PAMRasterBand band="2">
<PAMRasterBand band="3">
```

So the problem is in `gdalogr:warpreproject`. I used the same code you provided in a raster I have but the output is RGB, I don't know what's going on, maybe you should give a sample of your raster file.

## NOTE

The xml has no style data, as I said the raster you firstly saved is not a styled layer, but an actual RGB image representing the styled raster.