# Extracting one band from multiple stacking raster layers using PyQGIS?

Tags: raster, pyqgis, batch, extract

I've got 1000 (one thousand) RapidEye raster images. The stacking layers has bands 1, 2, 3 and 4. I need to extract the bands 1, 2 and 3, then save the new file discarding the band 4.

I've tried to save RGB bands in QGIS, using the "Rendered Image" function. It works. How do I do that in batch mode or Python script?

[image]

Comment: QGIS 2.12. Save as raster layer as...
This function works, but now I'd like to know how to create a python script to do that 1000 times.

Comment: Can you include a snippet of your code so far that illustrates where you are stuck, please?

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [QGis Save Raster as Rendered Image](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68803/qgis-save-raster-as-rendered-image)

Comment: @PolyGeo, for now I'm stuck in this part, because I don't know if it is possible to create a PyQGIS script to process these 1000 images.