# Exporting raster to rendered image using standalone script in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, raster, pyqgis, export

Using standalone script I loaded a layer, and now I need to export it as an image. See code below:

```
 from qgis.core import *
 from qgis.utils import *
 from qgis.gui import *
 from PyQt4.QtGui import *
 from PyQt4.QtCore import *
 QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis", True)
 qgs = QgsApplication([], True)
 qgs.initQgis()
 rasterpath = "E:/MODIS DATA/2016/15-10-2016/TIRUNELVELI.tif"
 lyr = QgsRasterLayer(rasterpath, "TIRUNELVELI")
 QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)
```

I checked the post [QGis Save Raster as Rendered Image](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68803/qgis-save-raster-as-rendered-image), but the code is executed using Python console. If I use the same code it shows an error:

> NoneType object has no attribute 'clone'.

Updated Code after Comment

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
rasterpath = "E:/MODIS/TIRUNELVELI.tif"
layer = QgsRasterLayer(rasterpath, "TIRUNELVELI")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
uri = "E:/MODIS/newStyleqgis.qml"
layer.loadNamedStyle(uri)
extent = layer.extent()
width, height = layer.width(), layer.height()
renderer = layer.renderer()
provider=layer.dataProvider()
crs = layer.crs().toWkt()
pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
pipe.set(provider.clone())
pipe.set(renderer.clone())
file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter('E:/MODIS/abcd.tif')
file_writer.writeRaster(pipe,
                       width,
                       height,
                       extent,
                       layer.crs())
```

updated but showing error as shown : [image]

Answer (score 2):

From [Python: Attribute Error - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/python-attribute-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something):

> NoneType means that instead of an instance of whatever Class or Object
>   you think you're working with, you've actually got None. That usually
>   means that an assignment or function call up above failed or returned
>   an unexpected result.

The error is probably given by the path of your layer because there is a blank space.

For example, try to add an underscore to the pathname (you need to make the change in the system folder too):

```py
rasterpath = "E:/MODIS_DATA/2016/15-10-2016/TIRUNELVELI.tif"
```

or change the input folder.

Comment: check the updated code . i do so as u told. but raster is not saved as an image .

Comment: I just used your code for a test (using another path and other files), and it worked... I'm sure that the issue is due to your filepath or filename: have you moved your file to the path `E:/MODIS/`? Otherwise, there is some problem with the reading of your `E` drive.

Comment: Did u also run stand alone script ?? yeah i moved my file to the MODIS Folder. i will check it for giving another drive .

Answer (score 2):

Along with what [HowToInQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/87487/howtoinqgis) mentioned,  I think you also need to include the `QgsApplication` class in your updated code. Putting this together with your code works (note that you may need to escape your backslashes `"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis"` to something like `"C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis"`):.

Here is the complete code which worked for me:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis", True)
app = QApplication([], True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

rasterpath = "C:/Users/You/Desktop/New folder/vir.tif"
layer = QgsRasterLayer(rasterpath, "TIRUNELVELI")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
uri = "C:/Users/You/Desktop/style.qml"
layer.loadNamedStyle(uri)
extent = layer.extent()
width, height = layer.width(), layer.height()
renderer = layer.renderer()
provider=layer.dataProvider()
crs = layer.crs().toWkt()
pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
pipe.set(provider.clone())
pipe.set(renderer.clone())
file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter('C:/Users/You/Desktop/result.tif')
file_writer.writeRaster(pipe,
                       width,
                       height,
                       extent,
                       layer.crs())
```

[image: Result]

*Note the `0` at the end indicating it was successfully written.*

[image: Desktop image]