# How to include colors in 16bits one band raster

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, colormap

I have many 16bits one band rasters (geotiff), who basically are in greyscale.
I had created a style for a color representation with "Singleband pseudocolor" in QGIS and save a qml file.
But for my customers, who don't all have geomatic services, it's easier to open a tiff with colors directly. But keep raster value is needed because some of customers want to use it.

Is it possible to include color in my tiff and if yes, how?

I can use QGIS, SAGA and python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QGis Save Raster as Rendered Image](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68803/qgis-save-raster-as-rendered-image)

Comment: But we loose raster values. I would like to keep it. I'll precise my question.

Comment: The term you need to look for is colour/color table or palette.

Comment: I don't think QGIS can do this, you can with GDAL though https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/130199/2856

Comment: Ignore the`gdaldem` stuff, I think, just create a vrt, then `gdal_translate` the.vrt to new geotiff should copy the colour table over.